# Maven surefire tests - includes and excludes

Tags: maven, testing

I have a class **A.java** and two test classes, **ATest.java** and **AITests.java**. The ITest is for integration. The tests must be performed as:

1. When no Maven profile is selected only the Atest must be tested.
2. When the **itests** profile is activated the both tests (ATest and AITest) must be tested.

The problems is, when I use the command

```
mvn -P itests test
```

then only the ATest is tested, without the AITest. But I have no idea what I am missing here. Any hint?

My **pom.xml** is:

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*ITest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>itests</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>itests</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integration tests, please use the Maven failsafe plugin:

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/

You can skip it on the command line if you prefer.

Comment: One more thing. Is it possible to exclude the surefire tests when the failsafe plugin executes the IT tests?